# Change in bootstrap-select position of check-mark or 'glyphicon-ok' icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I hope that somebody can help me and others in my situation. I'm working with silviomoreto / bootstrap-select for select. Here is silviomoreto / bootstrap-select documentation: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

So I have a multiple select and I would like to know **how to show the check-mark or 'glyphicon-ok' icon in the left of the selected option**. By default is right align as picture shows.

[image: Right align example boostrap select]

The code that implements this multiple select is in the repository that I mentioned above and code that printed this select is the next:

```html
<!-- PREGUNTA NUMERO 7: ¿Recibió el recién nacido lactancia materna?--> 
<div id="pregunta_##ID7##_1" class="form-group templatemo_form">     
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <strong>##parto_enunciado7##</strong><br/>
  <td class="col-md-4">
          
   <select id="##ID7##_1" name="##ID7##_1[]" class="selectpicker" multiple data-width="100%" title="##valorSelect##">
    <option data-tokens="No nada" value="0">##no##</option>
    <optgroup label="Meses de lactancia...">
     <option data-tokens="Menos 3 meses" value="1">Menos de 3 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="3 6 meses" value="2">De 3 a 6 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="6 12 meses" value="3">De 6 a 12 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="Mas Más 12 meses" value="4">M&aacute;s de 12 meses.</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>
        
  </td>
  <br/>
 </div>
 <br/>
</div>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code so we can tell what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added code to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overwriting the CSS:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
    position: relative;
}
```

Note that the `.check-mark` has an `position: absolute` which are placing the element on the extreme right of the dropdown list.

Comment: Hi Silvio, first of all, thank you for your answer. It is very useful because it solves my problem partially. With your change, I've achieved that tick icon will be showed next to the option value (right side). What do you think? It would be possible to show tick icon on the left side of the option text?