# css bootstrap select move show tick mark to the left of text in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

Following the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806662/change-in-bootstrap-select-position-of-check-mark-or-glyphicon-ok-icon), I am trying to move the tick mark of the selector to the left of the option text. 
Here is the example on the site:
[image]

I tried to overwrite the css like this:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
    position: relative;
}
```

changing it to a `relative` position, but no sucess.

thanks in advance.

### update

there is an example on the [official website](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/):

```
<select class="selectpicker show-tick">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

### updatea 2

here is my bootstrap-selecter css file looks like:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 15px;
  /*margin-top: 5px;*/
  left:2px;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  margin-right: 34px;
}
```

Comment: can you add some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the following in your css:

```
    .bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5px; //changed from right:15
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Look at the image below:

[image]

And you are good to go.

Comment: @marcel Can you try updating your css with the code that I have given?

Answer (score 1):

Add `left` property to your css for the checkmark. Like this:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
  position: relative;
  left:2px;
}
```

Here's a working snippet (half of the code is from the question referred by OP)

```css
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 15px;
  /*margin-top: 5px;*/
  left:2px;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  margin-right: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


 <div class="col-md-8">
  <td class="col-md-4">
          
   <select id="##ID7##_1" name="##ID7##_1[]" class="selectpicker" multiple data-width="100%" title="##valorSelect##">
    <option data-tokens="No nada" value="0">##no##</option>
    <optgroup label="Meses de lactancia...">
     <option data-tokens="Menos 3 meses" value="1">Menos de 3 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="3 6 meses" value="2">De 3 a 6 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="6 12 meses" value="3">De 6 a 12 meses.</option>
     <option data-tokens="Mas Más 12 meses" value="4">M&aacute;s de 12 meses.</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>
        
  </td>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or similar please?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Do you mean for the code? Click on `Run code snippet`

Comment: please have a look at my css in the second update, i still can't make it work your solution.

Comment: remove `right:15px;` from your code and then try. Does it work?

Comment: okay. I updated my answer with the css you added in update two and it is working fine.

Comment: I think problem maybe that you are not adding your custom css in the very last. some other css is overriding it

Comment: i see that your example here is working, but how can i know what is overriding it on mine?

Comment: okay. can you join this chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132820/s-overflow007  .reply if you are unable to join it

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but the other member's answer fixed the problem. however, i know that your answer was a working example, but i couldn't make it work on mine.

Comment: It's okay. maybe the html was different in my example than your question

Comment: i have already upvoted it, that one upvote is mine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `.pull-left` class to the checkmark? It automatically has an !important tag which overwrites conflicting classes and add's a float to the left which should put it where you want it

Comment: how should I add it? where exactly, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
.show-tick.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu .selected span.check-mark{
    left: 15px;
}
```